# Looking for the history of Durin's rule in significant depth

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium

I'm looking for either/both

- **a)** a book/letter/canon source by Tolkien which explains the history of Durin's rule in significant depth (i.e., with more information than that found in Appendix A(III) in LotR); this can be any of the seven kings named Durin
- **b)** a list of all books/letters/canon sources by Tolkien which reference any of the seven kings named Durin.

I could not find an answer to a; my current findings for b are The Silmarillion; which details the creation of the dwarves by Aule and in particular the seven dwarf fathers, which include Durin I; the Lord of the Rings, which provides a lot of detail in Appendix A(III) as well as information sprinkled throughout the text, in particular Gimli's song in the halls of Moria, and some occasional references in the Hobbit. I've started to look at the first five volumes of The History of Middle Earth but most of the references there seem like only off-hand references.

Though I can't really recall much reference to Durin in the LotR movies, I haven't seen the Hobbit movies (and rather refuse too). I'd rather no references to the movies unless there's reasonable ways to infer that it is consistent with Tolkien's story or approved by Christopher Tolkien or in some other way definitively canon.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/axsfaiLN

Comment: Are you looking for a story you once read or recommendations? The latter is off-topic.

Comment: @Edlothiad neither, I'm looking for if Tolkien provided a detailed history of Durin I - VII in any of his works or alternatively a list of all references to Durin I - VII; I have checked some books but some books I do not own. I want to know for some research I'm doing.

Comment: @heather so recommendations of books on where you can read about Durin I-VII?

Comment: @Edlothiad I suppose so, but you seem to define it as "These types of questions provide some background information about the question asker in hopes that answerers can recommend new material for the question asker to consume, provide a fact or concept and ask for a list of all works that talk about said fact or concept, or ask for all the examples of the use of a work in popular culture." The second definition would be relevant, but I'm not asking for all things Tolkien but a very specific subset of Tolkien works...if this is off-topic then I apologize.

Comment: Good enough for me, I should have an answer posted any second now.

Comment: @Valorum Handy, though it does include a few instances of "During".

Comment: @TRiG - Yah, just a quick'n'dirty search to help whoever is writing a proper answer.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The largest complete history of Durin and his folk seems to be in Appendix A, Annals of the Kings and Rulers, Durin's Folk, unfortunately. Another extensive account likely exists in the History of Middle-earth Volume 12, People's of Middle-earth.'

For other references the below is a rough guide to a reference to each Durin.

## [Durin I](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Durin)

References to Durin I (the Deathless) include:

- The Silmarillion, "*Quenta Silmarillion: Of Aulë and Yavanna*"
- The Letters of J.R.R. Tolkien, Letter 212
- The People's of Middle-earth, "*Of Dwarves and Men*"
- The Fellowship of the Ring, "*A Journey in the Dark*"
- The Lord of the Rings, Appendix A, "*Durin's Folk*"
- The War of the Jewels, "*The Grey Annals*": §19
- The Fellowship of the Ring, "*The Bridge of Khazad-dûm*"
- The Lord of the Rings, Appendix B, "*The Third Age*"

Far less is known about most of the following Durin's as they were of lesser focus in Tolkien's works.

## [Durin II](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Durin_II)

References include:

- The Lord of the Rings, Appendix A, "*Durin's Folk*"
- The Peoples of Middle-earth, "*Of Dwarves and Men*"

## [Durin III](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Durin_III)

More is known about Durin III as he was one of the recipients of a Ring of Power.

References include:

- The Lord of the Rings, Appendix A, "*Durin's Folk*"
- The Lord of the Rings, Appendix B, "*The Second Age*"
- The Silmarillion, "*Of the Rings of Power and the Third Age*"
- The Lord of the Rings, Appendix B, "*The Third Age*"
- The Unfinished Tales, "*The History of Galadriel and Celeborn*"

## [Durin IV](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Durin_IV)

Again, very little is known about Durin IV

References include:

- The Lord of the Rings, Appendix A, "*Durin's Folk*"

## [Durin V](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Durin_V)

*None in canon*

## [Durin VI](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Durin_VI)

References include:

- The History of the Hobbit - The Fourth Phase
- The Lord of the Rings, Appendix A, "*Durin's Folk*"

## [Durin VII](http://tolkiengateway.net/wiki/Durin_VII)

References include:

- The Fellowship of the Ring, "A Journey in the Dark"
- The Lord of the Rings, Appendix A, "Durin's Folk"
- The Peoples of Middle-earth, "Of Dwarves and Men"